# Exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Tags: java, exception, iterator

I'm trying to iterate using and Iterator object but I keep getting IndexOutofBound Exception. This is my code.

```
Iterator rows = myList.get("Table");
while(rows.hasNext())
{
Row row = (Row)rows.next();
//do something with row
}
```

The exact line I'm getting the exception is 'Row row = (Row)rows.next();'. From the exception, I'm assuming that there is no more data in rows and hence rows.next() results in the exception. But if that is the case, shouldn't rows.hasNext() returned false? How is that rows.hasNext() returns true but rows.next() results in an exception? What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show [a complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the behaviour?

Comment: Maybe a hint if you are using multithreading can exclude some error case...

Comment: Yes, I am using multithreading. Could it cause any issues?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern looks okey... Is the Iterater you get an own Implementation of 'Iterable'? Then it could be a wrong condition in the 'hasNext' method...

If it's an own implementation - you should also change it to:

```
Iterator<Row>
```